# How to create model objects that belong to unique user

Tags: django, model

I am setting up a delivery app .I want to be able to create a Reciever that belongs to the user logged in when created.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False)

class Reciever (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=False)
```

I want to create a Reciever object that belongs to a particular user.
When i create a Reciever now , it is available to all users.

Comment: Deleted my comment because Willem's is more detailed. Note you have the 'e' and the 'i' backwards in Receiver, so if you are trying to copy and past his answer, make sure to fix that!

Answer (score 2):

In that case you can use a [**`OneToOneField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField), which is a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey), but with a *uniqueness* constraint attached to it, like:

```
class Reciever(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In the view, you can thus attach the logged in user to the `Receiver`, like:

```
def some_view(request):
    Receiver.objects.create(name='foo', user=request.user)
```

given of course you already [made `CustomUser` your customer model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model).

If you made a `ModelForm`, you can exclude the `user` field, and set it in the view, for example:

```
def some_view(request):
    form = ReceiverForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        object = form.save(commit=False)
        object.user = request.user
        object.save()
        # ...
    # ...
```